# Analyse firebase geodata

Tags: android, firebase

I am writing geo app for android with firebase and java. This app should save user's geotracks and some useful information about it. 
Now I want to create some beautiful charts which should visualize data from database. For example, linear chart of travel activity during the day for every user. Which library or framework is the best for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use geofire for Java https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java for indexing and querying firebase geospatial indexes.